# Problema para carregar view

Tags: php, codeigniter, redirect

Olá, eu estou consumindo uma API no meu controller e, ao receber o resultado, eu gostaria de carregar uma view do painel do usuário. Porém quando o script chega no método `$this->load>view()` nada acontece. Eu depurei para saber se as informações estão chegando no controller e se o a execução entra na condicional e a resposta é sim, porém a view não é carregada. Também tentei dar um `redirect('Controller/Action', 'refresh')` mas também não funcionou, nada acontece. Agradeço se algum puder ajudar.

**Função que faz o submit para o controller:**

```
    $('#form').validate({
    submitHandler: function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: appPath + '/' + controller + '/' + action,
            dataType: 'JSON',
            data: $('#form').serialize(),
            cache: (false),
            async: (false),
            success: function (data) {
                alert(JSON.stringify(data));
            },
            error: function (err) {
                alert.log(err);
                //semanticAlert(err);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

**.../controllers/Usuario.php:**

```
public function autenticar() {
    try {
        $credenciais = $this->input->get();

        $headers = array(
            'xAuthChaveApi: ' . API_KEY,
            'login: ' . $credenciais['login'],
            'senha: ' . $credenciais['senha']
        );

        $response = curlRequest('GET', Enum::authUsuario, $headers);

        if (isset($response['data']) && $response['meta']['status'] == 'success') {
            $this->session->set_userdata($response['data']);

            $dados = array(
                'titulo' => 'Painel de Controle',
                'nomeView' => 'dashboard/home'
            );

            $this->load->view('menu', $dados);
        }
        //echo json_encode($response['meta']);
    } catch (Exception $ex) {
        die($ex->getMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: Estou dando o submit do form html com Ajax. Vou incluir o código no post.

Comment: Cara, eu quero renderizar o menu com PHP e passar os dados recuperados pela pela função curlRequest para o javascript pra poder manipular alerts e coisas do tipo.

Comment: Fiz outra edição no post pra ficar melhor compreendido. Nessa função eu valido o form e mando pra o controller, que, por sua vez, faz uma requisição para uma API que retorna os dados do usuário, quando os dados chegam no controller eu quero carregar uma view e passar os dados para o javascript pois baseado no status retornado pela APi quero exibir uma notificação ao usuário.

Comment: Consegui fazer funcionar parcialmente aqui, porém como eu tô carregando a página e imprimindo a resposta ao mesmo tempo dá erro na chamada Ajax(acho que é por isso). Como posso carregar a página e ao mesmo tempo passar a mensagem de saída da API para o java script? Segue o responseText atual:

{"status":"success","message":"Usuario autenticado com sucesso."}<!DOCTYPE html>↵<html lang="pt-br">↵    <head>↵        <meta charset="utf-8">↵....

Comment: Eu usei ajax somente para poder pegar a resposta no javascript, eu poderia ter usado o submit padrão e usar somente PHP mas eu gostaria de poder realizar alguma operações baseado na resposta que eu recebesse da API.

Comment: Então, eu tava só testando pois quando eu receber a resposta o que eu vou fazer é mostrar uma notificação com o texto da resposta.

Comment: Eu agradeço muito por toda paciência. Eu dicidi deixar o PHP em cargo de todas essas notificações, vai ser de uma forma mais estática porém sem gambiarras. Obrigado.